# Include my Javascript animation on all the html body so it stays while scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Hi i'm learning html/css and javascript and I think I'm having an issue with my html structure. Basically what I want to do is that my particles animation stays on the website while scrolling the page. I have a Javascript file that does a getElementById('particles') to run the canvas on a div but it only stays on the first page.

I tried to move the "particles" div as a main div that will contain all the sections but it didn't work.

Here's the repository of the files if anyone is interested: https://github.com/DanielVillacis/DanielVillacis.github.io

Here's my html structure :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  particleground(document.getElementById('particles'), {
    dotColor: '#FFFFFF',
    lineColor: '#FFFFFF'
  });
  var intro = document.getElementById('intro');
  intro.style.marginTop = -intro.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
}, false);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

header,
section {
  display: block;
}

#particles {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <main role="main">
      <section class="intro">
        <div id="particles">
          <header class="splash" id="splash" role="banner">
            <div id="intro">

            </div>
          </header>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="AboutMe">
        <div class="introduction">
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="box">
        <div class="projectContainer">
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="Contact">
        <h2 class="ContactTitle">Contact</h2>
        <div class="contactLinks">
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `particleground` is not defined, please include its code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `position: fixed;` property.

With position set to fixed, your canvas is positioned relative to the viewport and hence would remain even while scrolling.

```css
.pg-canvas {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put the particles (which are shown on a canvas) into a section which will scroll out of view.

The particles library you are using places this canvas just before the element you have given it, which has id particles.

You can fix just the canvas by adding `position: fixed` to the canvas selector in your style sheet (watch out if you have other canvases to give a more definite selector).

This will work in many cases to fix the canvas with the particles to the viewport. But note this description from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative
> to the initial containing block established by the viewport, except
> when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter
> property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms
> Spec), in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block.
> (Note that there are browser inconsistencies with perspective and
> filter contributing to containing block formation.) Its final position
> is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

You are OK at the moment because you move intro with top but if that were a translate you’d have to put the canvas out of intro.